# Why does auto seemingly deduce a reference when using structured bindings?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Consider the following code that uses structured bindings from C++17:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
auto [x, y] = std::tie(a, b);
y = 1;
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
```

Since I used `auto`, I would expect the code to print `0 0` as `y` should be a copy. However, it prints `0 1`. Why? I thought that a bare `auto` never deduces a reference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) notes, the portion of the declaration preceding `[` (i.e. `auto` in your case) does not apply to the introduced identifiers. Instead, it applies to a hidden variable that is created by the compiler under the covers. Your structured-binding declaration

```
auto [x, y] = std::tie(a, b);
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
auto e = std::tie(a, b);
decltype(std::get<0>(e)) x = std::get<0>(e);
decltype(std::get<1>(e)) y = std::get<1>(e);
```

As you can see, `auto` is applied to the hidden variable `e` and not to the declaration of `x` and `y`. The type of `e` is `std::tuple<int&, int&>`, and `decltype(std::get<1>(e))` gives you `int&`.

Comment: Usage of `decltype` here is slightly incorrect. `std::get` for tuples always returns a reference (to allow mutating tuple elements), but `auto [x] = std::tuple<int>(5)` will deduce `int`, not `int&`. correct type here is `tuple_element_t<0, decltype(e)>`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot `x` is an alias to the member of the hidden variable. It ___is___ a reference in this sense. Though `decltype` has special handling that makes it not appear like a reference.

Comment: @Revolver `tuple_element<...>&`